# How to create an emacs key-chord with 'home' key

Tags: emacs

I would like to press 'home' twice to take me to the beginning of the buffer.  I can't get the syntax right.  The following do not work and I can't find the answer with google...

```
;; key chords
(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)
;(setq key-chord-two-keys-delay 0.2)
;(key-chord-define-global "(home)(home)" 'beginning-of-buffer)
;(key-chord-define-global "[(home)(home)]" 'beginning-of-buffer)
;(key-chord-define-global (home)(home) 'beginning-of-buffer)
;(key-chord-define-global [home][home] 'beginning-of-buffer)
```

Update: I've switched to the key-combo package, which does work with multiple key-presses including the home key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `key-chord` won't help in this instance, as `<home>` isn't in its supported character range.

I believe the following should do what you're wanting, and the same pattern can easily be used for other unsupported keys<sup>1</sup>:

```el
(defvar my-double-key-timeout 0.25
  "The number of seconds to wait for a second key press.")

(defun my-home ()
  "Move to the beginning of the current line on the first key stroke,
and to the beginning of the buffer if there is a second key stroke
within `my-double-key-timeout' seconds."
  (interactive)
  (let ((last-called (get this-command 'my-last-call-time)))
    (if (and (eq last-command this-command)
             last-called
             (<= (time-to-seconds (time-since last-called))
                 my-double-key-timeout))
        (beginning-of-buffer)
      (move-beginning-of-line nil)))
  (put this-command 'my-last-call-time (current-time)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'my-home)
```

Note that `this-command` will evaluate to `my-home` when the function runs, so we are setting the `my-last-call-time` property on the `my-home` symbol, thus neatly avoiding the need to maintain a separate variable for remembering when this function was last called, which makes the function nicely self-contained and re-usable: to make another similar function, you need only change `(beginning-of-buffer)` and `(move-beginning-of-line nil)`.

<sup>1</sup> The obvious caveat is that *both* commands execute in succession if you trigger the double-key behaviour, so don't use this approach with commands for which that will be a problem.

(Conversely, the *advantage* is that we're not messing with timers.)

Answer (score 3):

It is `<home>`. To find out how emacs calls a particular key — one can press that key, and `M-x view-lossage` after that.

**Edit**

Sorry, misunderstood Your question at first. `M-x key-chord-define-global` doesn't accept `home` key. So I think currently this can't be done.

Comment: `view-lossage` is fine, but for checking a single key I always recommend `C-h k` or `C-h c`.

Comment: Yes, `key-chord-define-global` says: "KEYS can be a string or a vector of two elements. Currently only elements that corresponds to ascii codes in the range 32 to 126 can be used."

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `smartrep.el` which has the advantage of handling this sort of thing in a non-hacky way. The disadvantage is, of course, a dependency on a library.

```
(require 'smartrep)

(defun beginning-of-line-or-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (run-at-time 0.2 nil #'keyboard-quit)
  (condition-case err
    (smartrep-read-event-loop
      '(("<home>" . beginning-of-buffer)))
    (quit nil)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<home>") #'beginning-of-line-or-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `key-chord` for this. Remove the calls to `key-chord-define-global` from your `.emacs` file and add the following lines instead:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<home>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<home> <home>") 'beginning-of-buffer)
```

**Explanation**:

`<home>` is bound to `move-beginning-of-line` by default. If you want to be able to set up a key binding that consists of two presses of `<home>`, you first have to remove the default binding using `global-unset-key`. Then you can add the desired binding for `beginning-of-buffer` to the global keymap.

Comment: I suspect the intention was that `<home>` *continues* to move to the beginning of the current line, but `<home> <home>` would move to the beginning of the buffer. If that's correct, then this solution won't help.